# Cost of Performance on using setInterval to poll CLEDITOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, cleditor

I am using the [CLEditor WYSIWYG](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/) and trying to do a workaround to access the iframe content and count the characters (I know the whole debate on how you shouldn't limit characters on WYSIWYG, but I need to show the text representation of how many characters the user has entered(Don't care how much actual HTML is being generated). I was able to acheive the character count by using **setInterval()** as the event hook for CLEditor's change only fires on blur.

My Real Question:

**Is using setInterval() detrimental to performance or is there another method I should be using to poll for changed text?**

Here is the method I am currently using:

```
       function checkChange(){
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var t = $("#edFrame").contents().find("body").text().length;

                $(".limitCounter").text(t);

            });
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".wysiwyg").cleditor();


            setInterval('checkChange()', 50);


        });
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO you're going about this the wrong way. You should set up an event handler that fires an event when the text is changed. Since you're using jQuery, have a look at jQuery events: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/. Specifically, read up on the `.change()` event, since I think that this is what you want to use. You attach an event to your object (`#edFrame`), and specify a function to be invoked when that event is fired.

You've implemented a busy-wait system which, while it works, is far from the best design and will probably cause headaches for you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous comment, this could be done like that:

```
$("#edFrame").cleditor().on('change', function () { 
   var t = $(this)[0].$area.val().length;
   $(".limitCounter").text(t)
});
```

Bear in mind that length shown counts the text characters and also the formatting tags.